# SwiftUI List onTapGesture covered NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to hide keyboard when tapped the list background, but onTapGesture will cover NavigationLink. Is this a bug or have a better solution?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("NextPage", destination: Text("Page"))
                
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                
                // hide keyboard...
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

> update

Thanks to asperi, and I found an alternative way: just put it in section header. As for style, we should create a custom ButtonStyle for NavigationLink.

Here is an example of using InsetGroupedListStyle.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(
                    header: NavigationLink(destination: Text("Page")) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("NextPage")
                                .font(.body)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.forward")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                                .font(Font.caption2.bold())
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.tertiaryLabel))
                            
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 12)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                    .textCase(nil)
                    .buttonStyle(CellButtonStyle())
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                    .padding(.horizontal, -16)
                ) {}
                
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
                
            }.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
            .onTapGesture {
                
                // hide keyboard...
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CellButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(
                configuration.isPressed
                    ? Color(UIColor.systemGray5)
                    : Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
            )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible direction to solve this - by making all taps handled simultaneously and navigate programmatically. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
truct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                MyRowView()
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
            }
            .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {

                // hide keyboard...
                UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct MyRowView: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink("NextPage", destination: Text("Page"), isActive: $isActive)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                DispatchQueue.main.async { // maybe even with some delay
                    self.isActive = true
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you want to pass value item to new view? Would be just to create a new prop on the rowView and pass it through `destination: NewView(item)`?